# Can't Click on the First Image in the crossfading effect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
var timer = setInterval(nextImage, 4000);
var curImage = 0;
var numImages = 2;

function nextImage() {
    var e;
    // remove showMe class from current image
    e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
    removeClass(e, "showMe");

    // compute next image
    curImage++;
    if (curImage > numImages - 1) {
        curImage = 0;
    }

    // add showMe class to next image
    e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
    addClass(e, "showMe");
}

function addClass(elem, name) {
    var c = elem.className;
    if (c) c += " ";  // if not blank, add a space separator
    c += name;
    elem.className = c;
}

function removeClass(elem, name) {
    var c = elem.className;
    elem.className = c.replace(name, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");  // remove name and extra blanks
}



$('#cf4a').on('click', '.slide.showMe', function () {
    let url = $(this).attr('data-url')
    console.log(url)
    //location.href = url (this is where the user should go when clicking on the image)

})
```

```css
#cf4a {
    position: relative;
    width: 5em !important;
}

.container {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 60vh;
}

.slide {
    border: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}

.showMe {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="cf4a">
      <img id="slideimg0" data-url="/actor/al-pacino/" class="slide showMe" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/8f/a0/51/8fa051251f5ac2d0b756027089fbffde--terry-o-neill-al-pacino.jpg" width="500">
      <img id="slideimg1" data-url="/actor/patrick-stewart/" class="slide" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ee/85/08/ee850842e68cfcf6e3943c048f45c6d1.jpg" width="500"
          style="position: relative; left: -5rem;">
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Run the code Snippet and click on the image, the URL situated in `img data-url="/ /"` should be printed on the console. For some reason console doesn't print when clicking on the first img having class `.showMe`. `/actors/al-pacino`is somehow not printing. Because the `.showMe` is dynamically added and removed I used the `.on()` function of JQUERY but this doesn't work on the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both images are absolutely positioned to the same place, the click event isn't being sent properly to the image that's visible.

Use the `pointer-events` style to prevent clicks from being sent to the hidden images.

I've also changed the `addClass()` and `removeClass()` functions to use the `classList` property rather than performing string operations on `className`.

```js
var timer = setInterval(nextImage, 4000);
var curImage = 0;
var numImages = 2;

function nextImage() {
    var e;
    // remove showMe class from current image
    e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
    removeClass(e, "showMe");

    // compute next image
    curImage++;
    if (curImage > numImages - 1) {
        curImage = 0;
    }

    // add showMe class to next image
    e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
    addClass(e, "showMe");
}

function addClass(elem, name) {
    elem.classList.add(name);
}

function removeClass(elem, name) {
    elem.classList.remove(name);
}



$('#cf4a').on('click', '.slide', function () {
    let url = $(this).attr('data-url')
    console.log(url)
    //location.href = url (this is where the user should go when clicking on the image)

})
```

```css
#cf4a {
    position: relative;
    width: 5em !important;
}

.container {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 60vh;
}

.slide {
    border: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.showMe {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="cf4a">
      <img id="slideimg0" data-url="/actor/al-pacino/" class="slide showMe" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/8f/a0/51/8fa051251f5ac2d0b756027089fbffde--terry-o-neill-al-pacino.jpg" width="500">
      <img id="slideimg1" data-url="/actor/patrick-stewart/" class="slide" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ee/85/08/ee850842e68cfcf6e3943c048f45c6d1.jpg" width="500"
          style="position: relative; left: -5rem;">
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```